# Lebesgue Dominated Convergence theorem question

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Prove $$\lim_{r\to 1^-}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{d\theta}{(1+r^2\cos2\theta)^{\frac{1}{3}}}= 
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{d\theta}{(1+\cos2\theta)^{\frac{1}{3}}}    $$

**Answer by Parcly** By symmetry considerations we can integrate only over $[0,\pi/2]$ – the other three parts are congruent. Then for any sequence of integrands $f_n(\theta)=(1+r_n^2\cos2\theta)^{-1/3}$ with $r_n\to1^-$ (pointwise convergence) and for all $\theta\in[0,\pi/2)$
$$0\le f_n(\theta)\le(1+\cos2\theta)^{-1/3}=\cos^{-2/3}\theta\le2(\pi/2-\theta)^{-2/3}$$
Then $\int_0^{\pi/2}2(\pi/2-\theta)^{-2/3}$ converges. Hence, by the dominated convergence theorem, the limit can be moved inside the integral.

**Question** How to apply Dominated convergence theorem? We have to find an upper bound of the integrand which is independent of $r$.?

Comment: Please answer, I will give a check mark.

Comment: $$ \lim_{x \to a} h(x) $$ exists if and only if, for every sequence $(x_n)_n$ for which $x_n \to a$ and $x_n \neq a$, the limit $$\lim_{n \to \infty} h(x_n) $$ exists.

You do not have to necessarily find an upper bound independent of $r$. Just use the  result I previously mentioned, and for every such sequence, you can apply the DCT.